# Javascript function to show only selected cards

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, animation

I have 4 options. ALL / PROJECTS / CERTIFICADOS / APIs.

I 13 cards in a grid. I want to define two properties to each card. For example, Card one will have ALL and PROJECTS.

I define "display:none" to the grid, and i want the user select one of the options, like PROJECTS and them show the PROJECTS cards, the same for ALL, CERTIFICADOS and APIs, with a little animation when showing the cards. How can i make the javascript code for this project? HELP!!

I tried define variables for ALL / PROJECTS / CERTIFICADOS / APIs, and put each variable in the card, but didnt work..
THE HTML OPTIONS:

```
<div class="blocks" id="button-container">
            <a href="#"><span class="block1">All</span></a>
            <span class="block2">Projetos</span>
            <span class="block3">Certificados</span>
            <span class="block4">APIs</span>
        </div>
```

javascript code:

```
  var allOption = document.querySelector("a#all-option");
  var projectsOption = document.querySelector("a#projects-option");
  var certificatesOption = document.querySelector("a#certificates- 
  option");
  var apisOption = document.querySelector("a#apis-option");
  var cardsContainer = document.querySelector("#cards-container");

 function exibirCards(tipo) {
var cards = document.querySelectorAll("#cards-container > .card");

for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
  if (tipo === "all") {
    cards[i].style.display = "block";
  } else if (cards[i].classList.contains(tipo)) {
    cards[i].style.display = "block";
  } else {
    cards[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}
}

allOption.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
exibirCards("all");
});

projectsOption.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
exibirCards("projetos");
});

certificatesOption.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
exibirCards("certificados");
});

apisOption.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
exibirCards("apis");
});

cardsContainer.style.display = "none";
```

Comment: add your javascript codes to question!

Comment: Done, wait for help haha